# How to delete several repeating triplets from a big text using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
class RNAtoAA
  def self.rna_convert(rna)
    rna.slice!"AUG"
  end
end
```

I tried this to delete "AUG" (I also need to delete 2 more repeating patterns) but it did not produce the desired result. I also tried `.gsub("AUG", "UAA")`

Comment: _"it did not produce the desired result"_ – what _is_ the desired result? How does `rna` look like and what is `rna_convert` supposed to return?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The desired result is to produce .dat file with new sequence of letters from which "AUG", "UAA", "UAG", "UGA" are deleted. And all my trials did not produce any results. The length of file I want to apply this method for is quite big also (.dat)

Comment: "it did not produce the desired result" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = 'AAAAUG'
RNAtoAA.rna_convert(string)
puts string
# AAA
```

Seems to work as expected
If you want to return the updated string, use this:

```
class RNAtoAA
  def self.rna_convert(rna)
    rna.slice!"AUG"
    return rna
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The desired result is to produce .dat file with new sequence of letters from which "AUG", "UAA",  "UAG", "UGA" are deleted. And all my trials did not produce any results. The length of file I want to apply this method for is quite big also

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file in chunks so that the memory isn't swamped.
This example creates a testfile and uses it as source for a filtered version.
If you were to create a gigabyte big testfile you need to do the same thing for the creation of the testfile.
If your file contains linefeeds this could be simpler by lazy loading the lines but I'm going to assume it hasn't.

```
# create a testfile
patterns = ["AUG", "UAA", "UAG", "UGA","AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
large_string = ""
1_000_000.times{large_string << patterns.sample}
File.write("rna.dat", large_string)

#read the file, remove some patterns and write in a new file
filtered = ["AUG", "UAA", "UAG", "UGA"]
File.open("filtered.dat", "w") do |out_file|
  File.open("rna.dat", "r") do |in_file|
    while chunk = in_file.read(3)
      # Read small chunks of 3 bytes to limit memory usage
      out_file.write chunk unless filtered.include? chunk
    end
  end
end
```